# Interfacing both Debug and Release DLLs with the same C# code in SWIG?

Tags: c#, swig, dllimport

SWIG lets you specify the DLL to import in C# by using the `-dllimport` command line argument.

What about importing a DLL whose name depends on whether it is a Debug version or a Release one? This happens with DLLs that follow the Microsoft convention of appending the `d` suffix to the Debug version, e.g. `ucrtbase.dll` for the Release version, and `ucrtbased.dll` for Debug.

If `-dllimport` allowed to specify a symbolic constant, then the value of such constant could depend on whether `DEBUG` is defined or not, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: I'm not sure using a preprocessor directive would help here - when SWIG runs it doesn't know if you're compiling the DLL itself with DEBUG or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want using a static constructor and [the `SetDllDirectory` of suggestion of this this answer](http://swig3.0%20-DSWIG_CSHARP_NO_IMCLASS_STATIC_CONSTRUCTOR%20-csharp%20test.i).

To test this out I put together this example:

```
%module foobar

%pragma(csharp) imclasscode=%{
  [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
  static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

  static $imclassname() {
    if (isDebug)
      SetDLLDirectory("path/to/directory/with/debugDll");
    else
      SetDLLDirectory("path/to/directory/with/regularDll");
  }
%}
```

You have to build it with SWIG like this in order to [suppress the default static constructor](http://swig3.0%20-DSWIG_CSHARP_NO_IMCLASS_STATIC_CONSTRUCTOR%20-csharp%20test.i):

```
swig3.0 -DSWIG_CSHARP_NO_IMCLASS_STATIC_CONSTRUCTOR -csharp test.i
```

Quite how you'll distinguish `isDebug` in real code I'm less clear on - maybe use [this to find the current `HMODULE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1750114/168175) and then [`GetModuleFilename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to see if it's your debug build or not.

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work because the DLLs have different names. The problem is the DLL name that SWIG uses in `DllImport`, which is a literal string.

Comment: @Elena That's my point exactly, I think you can make it work despite that fixed literal string: by using two different directories, rename, them so they each have the same name and then picking which directory to use at load-time.

Comment: You can call swig with `-dllimport '"+somefunction()+"`, but that's not actually legal to do in C# annotations at all as far as I can see.